# PHP read a file into an array

Tags: php

I have a file (Test.txt) with the following data: 1,0

I am wanting to read the contents of this file into an array and then print the variables. Here is my current code:

```
    function readUserDetails($username) {
    $userDetails = explode(',', file($username.".txt"));
    print($userDetails[0].$userDetails[1]);
}
```

If I call the readUserDetails function with the folowing parameters: "Test", I get the following errors:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Users\s13\Game\Game6\default.php on line 128
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Users\s13\Game\Game6\default.php on line 129
>   Array

Can I please have some help to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file($username.".txt")` already returns you an array and you are trying to explode an array with `,`  delimeter

Try this

```
function readUserDetails($username) {
  $userDetails = explode(',', file_get_contents($username.".txt"));
  print($userDetails[0].$userDetails[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The PHP `file()` function reads a file into an array, one line of the file into each array element. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php. `explode()` expects a string. Look at what `file()` is reading to see if it's what you want:

```
<?php
   ...
   $userDetails = file($username.".txt");
   print_r($userDetails);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use file_get_contents() to return the contents of a file as a string.

$userDetails = explode(',', file_get_contents($username.".txt"));

Answer (score 0):

Try:

$array = explode( "\n", file_get_contents( $username .'txt' ) );